# Do any of the current gen console or handheld compilers support C++11?

Tags: c++

I am not asking for full support but do any of the current gen support C++11? I know VS C++ supports lambda and the auto keyword and I believe gcc supports both as well. Do any of the current gen consoles or handheld (3ds, sony vita) support it?

Comment: This belongs on SO.

Comment: @Duck: I don't think so, these compilers are _not_ widely available outside the game development community. If anything they are so locked down even anyone here who knows couldn't answer.

Comment: This is a very good question, if you're starting out on a project, and hope to be succesful you might dream of buying a PS3 or Wii devkit someday and port your game. Would be pretty painful if it turns out you're heavily relying on language features their compilers don't support.

Comment: I believe the Android toolchain supports C++0x.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the major gaming consoles do not have public development kits, and forbid sharing much information about the underlying SDKs. They do tend to trail a few years behind other platforms for cost and stability reasons. If you have development kits for these consoles or the resources to get them, you should be able to contact your licensor for details on C++0x support.

So I can't answer for any of the major gaming consoles, but perhaps more important for independent development, the iOS toolchain does not. Xcode is still based on GCC 4.2, and they're moving forward by switching to Clang/LLVM, not newer versions of GCC. [Clang keeps a feature matrix for C++0x support, and it's not nearly as complete as GCC's](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx0x). Picking some major features, variadic templates, auto, and rvalue references are present, but constexpr, defaulted/deleted methods, and lambdas are not.

Comment: To add on, if you are an indie developer or part of a company looking to develop for a certain system, you could always contact the company and ask whether they support or plan on support certain languages.

Comment: Just as an update, the newest Clang does have some seriously complete C++11 feature support.

Comment: -1: Answer needs updating to reflect current Clang C++11 feature support.